# Best way to paint multiple rectangle?

Tags: ios5, quartz-graphics

In my project I need to paint couple of hundred rectangles using Quartz painting. I do have such a code

```
-(void)RenderRectangles:(NSArray*)rectangles
                        fillColor:(UIColor*)fillColor 
                    strokeColor:(UIColor*)strokeColor 
            strokeThickness:(float)strokeThickness;
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [strokeColor CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeThickness);

    for (NSValue *vRect in rectangles) {
    CGContextAddRect(context, [vRect CGRectValue]);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [fillColor CGColor]);
    for (NSValue *vRect in rectangles) {
    CGContextFillRect(context, [vRect CGRectValue]);
    }

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

It works ok, but I'm just wondering if is possible to do it using only one loop? Or is there a better way to stroke and fill a collection of rectangles?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more efficient to create a single path. Check out the following functions to create a single path with your rectangles, then you can fill and stroke the same path instead of needing to recreate it:

```
CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathAddRect()/CGPathAddRects()
CGContextAddPath()
```

...and for performance, remember to cache this path if you're going to draw it multiple times!